# Python & Opencv : Realtime Get RGB Values When Mouse Is Clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, rgb

I wrote a code that reads an image and get rgb values with coordinates of clicked pixel while you are clicking to screen with mouse. The working code is below;

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def mouseRGB(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: #checks mouse left button down condition
        colorsB = image[y,x,0]
        colorsG = image[y,x,1]
        colorsR = image[y,x,2]
        colors = image[y,x]
        print("Red: ",colorsR)
        print("Green: ",colorsG)
        print("Blue: ",colorsB)
        print("BRG Format: ",colors)
        print("Coordinates of pixel: X: ",x,"Y: ",y)

# Read an image, a window and bind the function to window
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
cv2.namedWindow('mouseRGB')
cv2.setMouseCallback('mouseRGB',mouseRGB)

#Do until esc pressed
while(1):
    cv2.imshow('mouseRGB',image)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
#if esc pressed, finish.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But what I want is; I don't want to read image, I want to see realtime camera stream in screen; and when I click somewhere, I want to see clicked pixel's rgb values and coordinates in anytime.

How can I edit my code?

Comment: cv2 has functions to read from camera - you should see it in any basic tutorial for cv2. https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: cv2 has also functions to draw figures and text on image https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To capture video add a capture object

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

`0` is the camera number for my webcam but if you have a 2nd usb camera then it'll probably be `1`

Then in your `while` loop read a frame from the video stream by adding

```
ret, frame = capture.read()
```

You can treat `frame` in exactly the same way as you treat any image.

Finally dont forget to release the capture object when you finish,

```
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Full code listing,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def mouseRGB(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: #checks mouse left button down condition
        colorsB = frame[y,x,0]
        colorsG = frame[y,x,1]
        colorsR = frame[y,x,2]
        colors = frame[y,x]
        print("Red: ",colorsR)
        print("Green: ",colorsG)
        print("Blue: ",colorsB)
        print("BRG Format: ",colors)
        print("Coordinates of pixel: X: ",x,"Y: ",y)


cv2.namedWindow('mouseRGB')
cv2.setMouseCallback('mouseRGB',mouseRGB)

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):

    ret, frame = capture.read()

    cv2.imshow('mouseRGB', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to show the rgb values in the header of the namedWindow?   Not sure why printing it would be of value as that would be in terminal window.   I guess you could also superimpose the rgb values on to the image.